# Is it valid to cancel powers in a numerical comparison?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I saw a YouTube video that asked, "Which is larger:
$\,3^{75}\,$ or $\,2^{100}$?"

The logic went something like this.

\begin{equation}
3^{75}\rightarrow3^{(25)^3}\rightarrow3^3=27\\
\\
2^{100}\rightarrow2^{(25)^4}\rightarrow2^4=16
\end{equation}

Is it valid to cancel the $\,25^{th}\,$ powers in the comparison as they have done in the third step above?

If they had asked
"Which is larger:
$\,3^{75}\,$ or $\,2^{125}$?" then $\,2^5=32\,$ would have been larger and I think this logic would hide the much larger power of $\,3\,$ growth that was canceled.

Comment: Between $3^{75}$ and $2^{125}$, the latter is indeed larger, so I don't understand the last paragraph.

Comment: Note that the normal way to read $3^{25^3}$ is as $3^{(25^3)}$ rather than as $(3^{25})^3$ for precisely this reason.  You can simplify the latter to $3^{75}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is clearer if you take the greatest common divisor of the power out;
$$3^{75}=(3^3)^{25}=27^{25}>16^{25}=(2^4)^{25}=2^{100}.$$

Answer (score 3):

It is valid but would be clearer if you wrote it as
$$3^{75}=\left(3^3\right)^{25}, 2^{100}=\left(2^4\right)^{25}$$.  Now you can see that you are applying the same power and just compare the bases.  In your $2^{125}$ example the base would be $2^5$ and indeed $2^{125} \gt 3^{75}$